# Getting the value of dynamically created text box in PHP

Tags: php

I have a link. Whenever it is clicked, a new page will be displayed which contains data such as `id`, `name`, `price` and a select option with a check box. This page also contains a button. All these details (`id`, `name`, `price`) are fetched from a table. If the check box is checked and the button is clicked, a new page with the selected values along with a text box for each id should be displayed. If a value is entered in those text boxes and the button is clicked, I should fetch the value of the text box. I have given the text box the name `id` (which is retrieved from the table).

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you're asking is possible, it sounds like simple form handling, but I don't understand it well enough to actually tell you how

Answer (score 1):

I assume the new text box is created using javascript. Give it a fixed `name` attribute that your PHP script knows and read it from _POST[]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two ways of doing this.

Name your text boxes as an array.  So the name would be `name[]` or `name[2]`.  Then, in PHP just loop over `$_POST['name']` which will be an array (or empty if no text boxes were added).  That way, you only need to submit the data that exists...

The other way would be to use Javascript to do the submission.  You'd need to assemble the response into a common format (JSON perhaps) and then send that to the server...

But it's definitely possible...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a naming convention for the name property of the textboxes that append an integer value to the end of the whatever generic name you use.  Store the number of textboxes created and once the page is posted, you can reconstruct the name of the textboxes with a loop and read the posted values.